# Unable to seperate the STRING in EXCEL in the desired way as it contains more than one ","

Tags: excel

The first column is written manually and I want the rest to be automated using the functions MID and FIND, if possible.
If not then by using any other functions.
I am using Excel 2016.

Screenshot of the problem in Excel:

[image]

The data to test:-

```
911 FORRESTAL DR, ARLINGTON, TX 76010
92 4th Street North, Providence, RI 02904
405 Fieldstone Drive, Dawsonville, GA 30534
551 Franklin Street, Circle Pines, MN 55014
545 Ashley Court, Fort Walton Beach, FL 32547
```

Comment: what formulas have you tried and where are they not working? This is more of a "help me with I've doen that's not working site, rather than a "write my code for me site".

Comment: You wouldn't need functions if you used the "text to columns" feature. Of course, this has to be repeated for every new sheet of data, so it may not be what you want.

Comment: text to columns would be tricky @JeroenMostert, since there is no comma / space pattern to use universally.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: from the data supplied (incomplete) it looks like splitting on commas and then splitting the last column (postal code) on a space would work. Of course, this doesn't work if street/place names can contain commas.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - good point. I didn't think of splitting twice.

Comment: It would be easier if you pasted the data directly so we do not need to retype it to test answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- B1 = `=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)`
- C1 = `=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)-FIND(",",A1)-2)`
- D1 = `=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)+2,2)`
- E1 = `=RIGHT(A1,5)`

fully tested against your sample data

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly, i was actually struck at the C1 and D1.